# CSS query not working on my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I've tried using several media queries I've found through Google to target the iPhone, but my site still isn't displaying like I want it to on the actual iPhone. It looks fine when I use iphone4simulator.com. Here's the media query I'm using now:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (resolution: 163dpi)
```

Here's the URL: [cfbpreview](http://www.cfbpreview.com)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this for the iPhone 4 because of the retina display.

```
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Here is a [link to all media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) you might need for a responsive design.

**IMPORTANT:** This will apply to all devices with a pixel ratio of more then 1.5. If you want it to be more specific to the device you will have to add more conditions to your meida query.

Comment: Just a note, that'll target a lot more than iPhone 4. It'll hit most recent high-end Android phones.

Comment: Of course. It will target all devices with a pixel-ratio of more then 1.5. Which is what you want. In this media query you can place the higher resolution images and other changes to retina display devices. If you want it to be specific to the iPhone 4 you will have to add more conditions specific to that device.

Comment: The user said "target the iPhone", so they may not want the Android devices. Just figured I'd point that out.